# jAlert is not working properly in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

jAlert is not working properly in a loop. It shows only the last message in the array. How can I solve this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.Messages.length; i++) {
    var item = data.Messages[i];
    if (item.Type == 1)
        jAlert(item.Message);
    else if(item.Type == 2)
        jAlert(item.Message);
}
```

Comment: Define "not working properly"

Comment: Given that the point of jAlert is to show a modal popup, how are you expecting to show more than one of them at a time?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan one after one.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that in a loop. You instead should place all the messages in to a single jAlert box

Comment: in some cases it is Alert ..in some other case it is Confirm. that is the problem

Comment: Also consider a switch case on your item types. @Rakin

Answer (score 2):

It is working as expected.

If you want them to appear one after another you may need to have a handler on close to show the next one.

Otherwise jAlert will only show the last one it was sent.